# Deleting template column

Tags: asp.net

Im using ASP.NET, with c#, with visual studio 2008.

I have a datagrid, and I have a Template column in the datagrid.
I have copied the datagrid from another .aspx. The template column is made for delete purposes(rows of data results),

but I don't need this template column anymore. So I have tried removing it. But when executing I get the error:
"System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException = specified argument was out of range. parameter name index."

The error is thrown when it reaches the line: DataGrid1.DataBind();

How can i fix this ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I had to modify some methods which were called in the InitializeComponent().
Thanks!